# issues with OS X 10.12.3 and X11 Fowarding to ubuntu

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, x11-forwarding

When attempting to run Firefox over X11 forwarding from OS X 10.12.3 to Ubuntu, I get "Error: no display specified"

However, when doing this from Linux to Linux it works no issues.

I validated my `/etc/ssh_config` and have it set with:

```
Host *
        SendEnv LANG LC_*

   ForwardX11 yes
   ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

I've tried both `ssh -X` and `ssh -Y` with no results. I've also tried to set this on OS X:

```
export DISPLAY='IP:0.0'
```

Without any success. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

macOS does not use X11 for its desktop interface. Unless you are specifically running a copy of Firefox which has been compiled to use X11 on macOS -- which would be very unusual! -- you cannot forward it over X11.